# document.onkeypress with browser console and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a store with iframe. Iframe is from third party payment provider where user can insert credit card number. I wanted to make sure there is absolutely no way that any script on my site could track that information. What makes me confused is if I put this into browser console:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert(charStr);
};
```

It will register the pressed key. I am pretty sure it is just browser console that can access it because document reflects to both parent and iframe document. But I want to make absolutely sure, is there any chance that javascript from parent document could track keypress in iframe?

Comment: Well did it work when you tried?

Comment: It worked if I put the code into browser console. But I don't have access to edit this page so I can not put javascript code to this page at the moment to try it. This is why this question.

Comment: If iframe is focused, events do not bubble out. Are you setting the script in the iframe or in the parent when you are running to console.

Comment: I am setting it in console.